# How convert and insert an 'int' in a 'char' for C++?

Tags: c++, insert, char, int

1. To convert any number (-19 | 34 | 0) in a 'char' ("-19" | "34" | "0")
2. To insert this 'char' in the middle of other 'char'

Are there already ready functions for conversion?

I tried with simple way of (+/- '0') but works only for number between 0 to 9

Comment: A "char" is a single character, while you have *strings*. And any descent text-book, tutorial or teacher should have taught you how solve the first part (converting a string to an integer).

Comment: Do you want an answer in C++ or in C (using char pointers)?

Answer (score 2):

A `char` only holds a single character, so is not a good choice for the destination type.

What you want is a `std::string`.

You can use

```
std::string s = std::to_string(-19);
```

and so on to convert the `int` -19 to a string.

You can then use the overloaded operators `+` and `+=` on the string class to join numbers together, or `std::string::insert` to insert a new string within an existing one.

Comment: OP might want to insert this number in an already existing string. In this case they could use a string formatting library, such as [Boost Format](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/format/doc/format.html). If string formatting is not possible (e.g. not allowed to add library, no liberty on input string, ...), then there is still [`std::string::insert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/insert)